# Getting Alert to work After a redirect on a login page

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication, alert

I have a page titled login.php, if a user successfully logs in, then he is redirected to map.php. There is also a hyperlink on login.php to map.php

map.php starts as follows:

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 if ($_SESSION){
 ?>
```

then output a bunch of HTML and JAVASCRIPT then...

```
 <?php } else {
 header ('Location: ../login.php');
 exit();
 $message = "wrong answer";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message'); 
 </script>";
 }
 ?>
```

If I start on login.php, and then click on the hyperlink to jump to the map without entering a username and password I see that the browser is refreshed and I have redirected myself back to the same page as desired, however how do I get the alert to work? I wish to let the user know that he must be logged in in order to view map.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wish to let the user know that he must be logged in in order to see the map.

You have mainly two different solutions to be able to handle the redirect.

### Handle the redirect with PHP

Instead of showing an alert, you can output a normal text and use the `refresh` header call in combination with the `url` header call in order to send a header to the client browser that refresh the page after a certain number of seconds.

```
<?php
}
else
{
    $message = "wrong answer";
    header('Refresh: 5; url=login.php'); 
    exit($message);
}
```

### Handle the redirect with Javascript

Just output the alert script that you have already written and then handle the redirect through javascript instead of using `header()` PHP function.

```
<?php
}
else
{
    $message = "wrong answer";
    echo "<script>
    alert('$message');
    window.location.href='login.php';
    </script>";
    exit;
}
```

---

I personally recommend to handle the redirect through PHP, since it is more elegant as solution and because you will not have to worry about users that have JavaScript disabled in their browser.

Comment: I was able to implement both solutions, thank you for that, however the problem I have with them is map.php is just a white screen flash, yet I wish to keep them on the same page (retroactively login.php). I was thinking of sending an alert with fancybox, and then refocusing back to the login form.  UX should be that if the link is clicked, and a session variable does not exist, either 1) alert with jscript or 2) output html to the same page so it looks nice. Or am I doing this incorrectly? i.e. its only a link if there is a session else it can follow either of the above rules.

Comment: just to clarify that what i would like to do is keep the user on the same page and only make the link into a link if there is a session variable otherwise it will output an alert, so i am guessing i need to do this in the header file itself where the link is located?

Comment: You can set up your `<a>` tag as `<a <?php echo $_SESSION ? 'href="map.php"' : 'href="javascript:alert(\'You need to log in.\');"' ?>>Map</a>`. Using ternery operators, if the session array exists you set the href attribute to redirect to map.php, otherwise set the href attribute to show up a window alert. p.s. There are more efficient methods to check if a user is logged in, search for it.

Comment: Thank you, your advice was quite helpful I did it the first way you suggested it was easy to implement. I was just curious how to do it the other way. from a completely academic standpoint..